# CURL error 'malformed' for Walmart API

Tags: magento-1.7, api, curl

I'm trying to send a request to Walmarts API but am getting a 'malformed' error when sending my GET request, hoping someone could help. Below is my code

```
class Admin2 {

    function __construct() {

    }
public function pkcs8_to_pem($der) {

      static $BEGIN_MARKER = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----";
      static $END_MARKER = "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";

      $value = base64_encode($der);

      $pem = $BEGIN_MARKER . "\n";
      $pem .= chunk_split($value, 64, "\n");
      $pem .= $END_MARKER . "\n";

      return $pem;
  }

  public function getClientSignature($url, $request_type, $timestamp) {
      // Your walmart info from walmart admin
      $walmart_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
      $walmart_consumer_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

      // Get an openssl usable private key from the walmart supplied secret
      $pem = $this->pkcs8_to_pem(base64_decode($walmart_secret));
      $private_key = openssl_pkey_get_private($pem);

      // Construct the data we want to sign
      $data = $walmart_consumer_id."\n";
      $data .= $url."\n";
      $data .= $request_type."\n";
      $data .= $timestamp."\n";

      // Sign the data
      $hash = defined("OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256") ? OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256 : "sha256";
      if (!openssl_sign($data, $signature, $private_key, $hash)) {
        // ERROR
        return null;
      }

      return base64_encode($signature);
  }

  public function walmartAPI(){

      if (!extension_loaded('openssl')) {
            'no openssl extension loaded.';
        }

     // Your walmart info from walmart admin
    $walmart_consumer_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    $walmart_channel_type = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

    $request_type = "GET";

    $url = "https://developer.walmart.com/proxy/item-api-doc-app/rest/v3/feeds?includeDetails=false&offset=0&limit=50";
    $url = urlencode ( $url );

    // We need a timestamp to generate the signature and to send as part of the header
    $timestamp = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

    $signature = $this->getClientSignature($url, $request_type, $timestamp);

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Accept: application/xml";
    $headers[] = "WM_SVC.NAME: Walmart Marketplace";
    $headers[] = "WM_CONSUMER.ID: ".$walmart_consumer_id;
    $headers[] = "WM_SEC.TIMESTAMP: ".$timestamp;
    $headers[] = "WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE: ".$signature;
    $headers[] = "WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID: ".mt_rand();
    $headers[] = "WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE: " .$walmart_channel_type;

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$requestUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $request_type);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec( $ch );

    if(curl_errno($ch)):
        echo 'Curl error: '.curl_error($ch);
    endif;

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

     print_r($xml);

  }

} // end class

$admin2 = new Admin2();

echo $admin2->walmartAPI();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your raw request/response data here so that i can help you.
1.Use this URI =>

```
https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/feeds/{feedId}?includeDetails={includeDetails}&limit={limit}&offset={offset}
```

Instead :

https://developer.walmart.com/proxy/

```
2.$url = urlencode ( $url );
```

DO NOT URLENCODE , REMOVE IT.